# Using scala constants in constant expressions

Tags: scala, annotations, constants

I have constants, that are made of other, smaller constants. For example

```
object MyConstants {
    final val TABLENAME = "table_name";
    final val FIELDNAME = "field_name";
    final val INDEXNAME = TABLENAME + "_" + FIELDNAME + "_ix"; // this one does not want to be constant
}
```

I want these to be true constants because I use them in annotations.

How do I make it work? (on scala 2.11)

What I want is

```
interface MyConstants {
    String TABLENAME = "table_name";
    String FIELDNAME = "field_name";
    String INDEXNAME = TABLENAME + "_" + FIELDNAME + "_ix";
}
```

but in scala. Scalac does not pick up constants for usage in annotations if it compiles them from java class/interface ([see SI-5333](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5333)) so I decided to put them in a scala object. It works for literals, and for expressions with literals, but not for expressions with other constants.

With this code:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Table
import org.hibernate.annotations.Index

object MyConstants {
    final val TABLENAME = "table_name";
    final val FIELDNAME = "field_name";
    final val INDEXNAME = TABLENAME + "_" + FIELDNAME + "_ix";
}

@Entity
@Table(name = MyConstants.TABLENAME)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
    appliesTo = MyConstants.TABLENAME,
    indexes = Array(new Index(name = MyConstants.INDEXNAME, columnNames = Array(MyConstants.FIELDNAME)))) 
class MyEntity {
}
```

I get a following error on line `indexes = ...`

> annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: MyConstants.INDEXNAME

Edit:
*After fiddling around with a few build configurations, I think this is actually a scala-ide specific issue. The code does indeed compile alright when I build project with gradle or sbt. I do use build tool for my actual projects, so in the end it's about having a few incomprehensible markers in the IDE - annoying, but has little to do with functionality.*

Comment: What do you mean with true constant and how do you measure what is a true constant and what not?

Comment: if its resolvable at compile time, its a true constant. dont know if the scala compiler will do that though.

Comment: @sschaef I mean constants that compile to the same bytecode as java's ```static final``` fields and can be used in annotations.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access them from Java?

Comment: @sschaef clarified it a bit in my post. I want to use them in annotations in scala code.

Comment: Can you please show an example that produces the error message?

Answer (score 3):

I used constants in JPA with scala. This code compiles, and I used it:

*FreeDays.scala*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "free_days")
@NamedQueries(
  Array(
    new NamedQuery(name = JpaQueries.IS_FREE_DAYS, query = "SELECT f FROM FreeDays f WHERE f.dateOfFreeDay = :" + JpaQueries.DATE)
  )
)
class FreeDays {

  def this(id: Int, name: String, dateOfFreeDay: Date) = {
    this()
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
    this.dateOfFreeDay = dateOfFreeDay
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  var id: Long = _

  var name: String = _

  @Column(name = "date_of_free_day")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  var dateOfFreeDay: Date = _
}
```

*JpaQueries.scala*

```
object JpaQueries extends JpaQueries

sealed trait JpaQueries {
  final val IS_FREE_DAYS = "IS_FREE_DAYS"
  final val DATE = "date"
}
```

Comment: After fiddling around with a few build configuration, I think this is actually a scala-ide specific issue. The code does indeed compile alright when I build project with gradle or sbt.